# Issue when using dask as parallel backend

Tags: python, dask

When I run my job using parallel backend as dask(joblib.parallel_backend('dask')) it interrupts after some time and throws this error. Any suggestions/recommendations to try? Below is my error screenshot. Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Please create a complete, verifiable example, with all imports and code we would need to recreate your problem. Then minimise it, to remove any things that are not related.

Comment: I think I resolved my issue. I was running multiple clients as below code

```python
some for loop:
      client = Client(processes=False)
      with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):
            #### Code goes here
```

Comment: You might want to write a concise answer to your own question explaining this, in case others get into the same situation.